# How can I include an external html file in my page?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to do:

```
<script src='bob.js'></script>
```

But using a html file, ie.

```
<script type='html' src='bob.html'></script>
```

The html file contains multiple JQuery templates, so it will have to parse the html file for  tags.

The src will be dynamic. I suspect the solution is JQuery, however I want it to be synchronous, just like with the first example.

How can I achieve this? I don't want to use another plugin, just native JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

you can get access to it using ajax:

```
function getPageObj(urlPath){
    var response =  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'html',
        async:false,
        cache:true,
        url: urlPath
    }).responseText;

    if(response==null ||response.length<1){return null;}
    var obj = $(response);

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: if I .append() that to a placeholder, will it treat any `<scripts>` inside it as scripts?

Comment: @[SLC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/174375/slc) yes, any `<script>` tags will be evaluated upon injection to the DOM. See [this comment](http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-67912032).

Comment: allow using cache or telling a beginner  to do so, will drive them mad

Comment: Good point, you don't want to cache until you have finalized your code.

Comment: @SLC: Getting the text from the response. Read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @Tomalak: Ah, cool! I thought the GET would return just the response text, I see it returns an XmlHttpRequestObject, pretty cool!